# Why is it necessary to add く in the following なる sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

This is the full sentence:

> お酒を飲みすぎると、気持ち悪くなる。

なる here means "to reach a certain state." The rest is easy to translate.

The only thing that confuses me is く. What does it mean here and why is it necessary?

Comment: What did you expect it to be? If that く wasn't there. Related question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62710/desconstructing-%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE/62711#62711).

Comment: @Tommy I expected the same sentence but without that character.

Answer (score 6):

You have to learn how to conjugate i-adjectives when it comes to expressing change using なる.
I recently answered a similar question, but that was posed in a different way so let me just get to the bottomline of what you want to know.

The basic construction rule when expressing change with なる is the following.:

> い-adj （－い＋く）＋なる Example たかい　>>>　たかくなる
>
> な-adj （－な＋に）＋なる Example きれいな　>>>　きれいになる
>
> nouns （＋に）＋なる Example せんせい　>>>　せんせいになる

And when it comes to negative:

> い-adj （－い＋く）＋ならない Example たかい　>>>　たかくならない
>
> な-adj （－な＋に）＋ならない Example きれいな　>>>　きれいにならない
>
> nouns （＋に）＋ならない Example せんせい　>>>　せんせいにならない

In your case 悪い is an i-adjective, hence 悪くなる.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, ～く is one possible conjugated form of i-adjectives, used in negative forms and when the adjective modifies a verb or another adjective (examples below).

> くらい　　→　くら**く**ない　(negative)
>
> わるい　　→　わる**く**なる　(adjective+verb)
>
> おいしい　→　おいし**く**食べる (adjective+verb)
>
> たのしい　 →　たのし**く**過ごす (adjective+verb)
>
> やすい　　 →　やす**く**ておいしい (adjective+adj)

etc.

Comment: I think your answer is missing something important. That `〜く is one possible conjugated form` does not explain **when** this form is used.

Comment: @virmaior edited to address your comment.