# Usage of に in たくさん人参を食べると、きれいになります。

Tags: grammar, particle-に

Is this right:

> たくさん[人参]{にんじん}を[食]{た}べると、きれい**に**なります。

Was に used correctly?

---

The example sentence I saw was:

> たくさんピザを食べると、おおきくなりますが、いつもスポーツをすることが好きです。

Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Is the first and second examples related? The former uses a na-adjective, the latter an i-adjective. Moreover, the latter doesn't look like a meaningful sentence.

Comment: Does this post help? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62801/9831

Comment: The second example makes no sense. Is pizza so nutritious?

Comment: The OP should post a tentative meaning so we can help. I welcome Lilly to the community!

Comment: たくさんピザを食べると**太る** (big)、でもスポーツするし大丈夫、みたいなことを言いたいんですかね‥

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are wondering if the use of に in the first sentence is correct because the second sentence is not using に in a sentence that seems similar to the first one.

First of all, these two sentences are both correct. 
Only the difference is that the first one is written in hiragana only, and the second one is written with some kanji.

> たくさん[人参]{にんじん}を[食]{た}べると、きれいになります

Now, let's look at the second sentence (Forget the last part of this sentence because it's not related in this case)

> たくさんピザを食べると、おおきくなります (correct)

The reason why you don't say

> おおきい　に　なります (wrong)

in this case is because `おおきい` is an i-adjective.

Here's the rules for `become`:

> If it becomes i-adjective （おおきい、ちいさい、ながい、etc), replace the last `い` with `く`
>
> Examples:
>
> おおきく　なります
>
> ちいさく　なります
>
> If it becomes na-adjective （きれい、しずか、べんり、etc), just add `に` before `なります`
>
> Examples:
>
> きれいに　なります
>
> しずかに　なります

So, the following two sentences are both **grammatically** correct.

> たくさん人参を食べると、きれいになります
>
> たくさんピザを食べると、おおきくなります